# INSERT array into separate rows MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, exploded

I have a dynamic Matrix box where users can unlimited drugs, the data comes through like this:

```
 [addindividuals] => [{"Drug":"Calpol","Strength":"100mg","Form":"Liquid","Quantity":"1"},{"Drug":"Paracetamol","Strength":"200mg","Form":"Tablet","Quantity":"16"}]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to have each line inserted into a new row (MySQL) and inserts into their relevant columns like so:

**Columns**: |  Drug  |  Strength  |  Form | Quantity

**Row1**    | Calpol | 100mg | Liquid | 1

**Row2**    |Paracetamol | 200mg | Tablet | 16

I'm guessing its using the exploded function> (I'm a novice) and then sql to insert the strings?

Comment: Read [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Thank you, I fairly understand that....but its getting it into separate rows I'm really struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the values as a json string collection,  First you need to explode then the string then use a for each to loop through each string then use another for each to make single row. Please have a below code this may help you.

```
$addindividuals = '{"Drug":"Calpol","Strength":"100mg","Form":"Liquid","Quantity":"1"},{"Drug":"Paracetamol","Strength":"200mg","Form":"Tablet","Quantity":"16"}';
$exploded_array = explode('},',$addindividuals);
$final_query = "INSERT INTO `table_name` (`Drug`,`Strength`,`Form`,`Quantity`) VALUES ";
$exploded_array[0] = $exploded_array[0].'}';
foreach($exploded_array as $exploded_element)
{
$single_row = '(';
$json_decode = json_decode($exploded_element,true);
foreach($json_decode as $key => $value)
{
    $single_row .= "'$value',";
}
$single_row = substr($single_row,0,-1);
$single_row .= '),';
$final_query .= $single_row;
}
$final_query = substr($final_query,0,-1);
echo $final_query;
```

Comment: Brilliant! this is exactly what I'm looking for for some reason when i try to run it, its not inserting any records?? it displays the final_query but not executing the INSERT

Comment: @MaxThorley i didnt write the code for inserting . You can use mysqli_query() to execute the query and insert records..:)